# Issue with wpf STA thread and

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

SO when I try to execute My Lines of Code

//Using Staements

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using TwitchLib;
using TwitchLib.Events.Client;
using TwitchLib.Models.Client;
```

//My line of Code

```
void PostMessage(string UserName,string UserType, bool isSub, string Message)
{
    StackPanel SP = new StackPanel();
    SP.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    TextBlock DT = new TextBlock();
    DT.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    SP.Children.Add(DT);
    TextBlock Caster = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock Type = new TextBlock();
    switch (UserType)
    {
        case "Broadcaster":
            Caster.Text = " CASTER ";
            SP.Children.Add(Caster);
            Type.Text = " MOD ";
            SP.Children.Add(Type);
            break;
        case "Moderator":
            Type.Text = " MOD ";
            SP.Children.Add(Type);
            break;
        case "GlobalModerator":
            Type.Text = " GMOD ";
            SP.Children.Add(Type);
            break;
        case "Staff":
            Type.Text = " STAFF ";
            SP.Children.Add(Type);
            break;
        case "Admin":
            Type.Text = " ADMIN ";
            SP.Children.Add(Type);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (isSub == true)
    {
        TextBlock Sub = new TextBlock();
        Sub.Text = " SUB ";
        SP.Children.Add(Sub);
    }
    TextBlock UName = new TextBlock();
    SP.Children.Add(UName);
    UName.Text = " " + UserName + ": ";
    TextBlock Mess = new TextBlock() ;
    Mess.Text = Message;
    SP.Children.Add(Mess);
    //ChatWindow.Text += DT + pretag + UserName + Message + Environment.NewLine;
    ChatWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => ChatWindow.Items.Add(SP)));
}
```

I pull this exception "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."

If I try this

```
void PostMessage(string UserName,string UserType, bool isSub, string Message)
{
Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
    //Same inside Code
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
}
```

I pull the exception 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

basically it treats the as if the invoking never happened
Can Some give me some advice.  I am Kind of new to using WPF.

Comment: Hi Bubba. Create a new WPF application project in Visual Studio - it will solve all your issues with threads. And create your controls in xaml. The way you try to start is for experienced WPF programmers.

Comment: You don't show the entry point, but based on your description it seems certain your program entry point doesn't have `[STAThread]` attribute on it. See marked duplicate.